# Magento Enterprise url rewrites vs url redirect

Tags: url-rewriting, magento-1.13, magento-1.12

Magento Enterprise 1.12 has `url rewrite management` tab in admin panel, but 1.13 version instead `url rewrite management` has `url redirects` tab. I see `enterprise_url_rewrite_redirect` table and `enterprise_url_rewrite` table both exists. What the difference? And where can I find `url rewrite management` tab in Magento Enterprise 1.13?

Answer (score 1):

Short:
`enterprise_url_rewrite` - this is the key table which make sure that end-users see the SEO/human friendly URLs
`enterprise_url_rewrite_redirect` - this table has redirect info about rewrite urls which are present in `enterprise_url_rewrite` table

Quoted from here (more detailed explanation is there as well): http://www.rahilnazir.com/url-rewriting-in-magento-ee-1-13/

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20160710230857/http://www.rahilnazir.com/url-rewriting-in-magento-ee-1-13/